# Align items in Row vertical not woking

Tags: flutter

I can't figure out how I can align my Icon buttons vertical in a row. Here is my code:

```
        Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.fast_rewind, size: 30),
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              onPressed: workoutBloc.player.hasPrevExercise ?  workoutBloc.player.previousExercise : null,
            ),
            IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.skip_previous, size: 30),
              onPressed: workoutBloc.player.hasPrevSet ? workoutBloc.player.previousSet : null
            ),
            IconButton(
              icon: workoutBloc.player.isPlaying ? Icon(Icons.pause, size: 45) : Icon(Icons.play_arrow, size: 45),
              onPressed: workoutBloc.player.hasEnded ? null :  () {
                setState(() {});
                workoutBloc.playPause();
              },
            ),
            IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.stop, size: 45,),
              onPressed: workoutBloc.player.state != 'REST' ? () {
                workoutBloc.stopSet();
              } : null
            ),
            IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.skip_next, size: 30),
              onPressed: workoutBloc.player.hasNextSet ? workoutBloc.player.nextSet : null,
            ),
            IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.fast_forward, size: 30),
              onPressed: workoutBloc.player.hasNextExercise ? workoutBloc.player.nextExercise : null
            )
          ],
        )
```

I have set the crossAxisAlignemnt to center but thats not working. I also tired `alignment: Alignment.center` for a Icon button but its not working either. It look like this:

[image]

Comment: When all icons have same size, are they aligned ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, the problem can be seen with the help of the Flutter Inspector. You are changing the Icon size in the icon object. Therefore the parent `IconButton` is not wrapping the size of it, instead it is pushing it.

[image]

For fixing it, if you move the size of the icon to `iconSize` property of the `IconButton`, you will have what you desired.

```
     Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          IconButton(
            iconSize: 30,
            icon: Icon(Icons.fast_rewind),
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            onPressed: null,
          ),
          IconButton(
              iconSize: 30,
              icon: Icon(Icons.skip_previous), onPressed: null),
          IconButton(
            iconSize: 45,
            icon: Icon(Icons.play_arrow),
            onPressed: null,
          ),
          IconButton(iconSize: 45, icon: Icon(Icons.stop), onPressed: null),
          IconButton(
            iconSize: 30,
            icon: Icon(Icons.skip_next),
            onPressed: null,
          ),
          IconButton(
              iconSize: 30,
              icon: Icon(Icons.fast_forward), onPressed: null)
        ],
      )
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! I didn't knew about Flutter inspector because I'm using VS Code, thats a great feature.